# How to sort by date before creating DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, dom, youtube

I am looping through some JSON and want to display DOM elements by latest date. I have a data-date attribute. How would I sort each object in array before creating them as DOM elements?

I have the following --

```
$.getJSON(ytapiurl, function(data) {
  $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
    var pubdate  = item['published']['$t'];
        htmlString +='<div class="cursor col-sm-6 col-md-3 item" data-date="' + fulldate '">Video</div>';

    console.log(new Date(pubdate).getTime());
 });
});
```

Comment: Uhm, so where exactly is `pubdate` coming from here ?

Comment: Where is `pubdate` defined and what is it's format?

Comment: Sorry, pubdate is a var set in the .each -- 
var pubdate  = item['published']['$t'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `pubdate` is a property of items in the `entry` array, you can sort the array before creating the html

```
$.getJSON(ytapiurl, function (data) {
    data.feed.entry.sort(function (a, b) {
        var fd1 = new Date(a.pubdate);
        var fd2 = new Date(b.pubdate);
        return fd1.getTime() - fd2.getTime();
    })
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
        var fulldate = new Date(pubdate).toLocaleDateString();
        htmlString += '<div class="cursor col-sm-6 col-md-3 item" data-date="' + fulldate '">Video</div>';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to sort array using the date object, not a string representing the date.

```
var articles = [
   {pubDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1), desc:'one'},
   {pubDate: new Date(1999, 0, 1), desc:'two'},
   {pubDate: new Date(2002, 0, 1), desc:'three'},
   {pubDate: new Date(2001, 0, 1), desc:'four'}
];
console.log(articles);
articles.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.pubDate < b.pubDate; // set desc or asc here
});
articles.forEach(function(article){
   console.log(article.pubDate,article.desc);
   // Write to DOM here
});
```

Returns

```
Tue Jan 01 2002 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) "three"
Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) "four"
Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) "one"
Fri Jan 01 1999 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) "two"
```